# How do you say Long Short-Term Memory in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

I am trying to write something formal about LSTM [Long Short-Term Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) in Spanish, I have:

- Memoria grande de corto plazo
- Memoria larga de corto plazo

But it doesn't sound good to me.

Comment: **Gran Memoria de Corto Plazo** sounds good to me.

Comment: doesn`t "Gran Memoria a Corto Plazo" sound better?

Comment: Could it be. What could be the criteria for `de` vs `a` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know anything about neural networks but in this paper

https://www.scribd.com/doc/295974898/Redes-Neuronales-Recurrentes

it is translated as **Redes de gran memoria de corto plazo (LSTM)** and you can find that on page 3.

I will add a picture of the fragment in case the site decides to change the article or the link becomes invalid.

> [image]
>
> **Redes de gran memoria de corto plazo** (LSTM): las redes recurrentes convencionales no pueden memorizar dependencias de largo plazo debido a que los gradientes retropropagados se desvanecen (o crecen sin límite) con el tiempo. Las redes LSTM incorporan una memoria explicita que puede ser actualizada y borrada lo que les permite aprender dependencias de largo plazo en los datos. Actualmente 2015, son muy populares porque son fáciles de entrenar (Vinyals et al. 2015).

Answer (score 1):

I found "memorias de corto a largo plazo" on [an article in Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_neuronal_artificial) and "modelo de memorias de largo a corto plazo" on [a thesis](https://books.google.cl/books?id=6nGnDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA209&lpg=PA209&dq=tecnica%20de%20busqueda%20por%20cadena&source=bl&ots=glA8dm1gJv&sig=hevQCsRL0C9FheaHGkDmkv-rcfs&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkoviA1oDaAhUBUZAKHXbVA-oQ6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q=cadena&f=false).

Comment: I think you're mixing the terms, the question is about a Long size for a short-term memory (Memoria grande a corto plazo) and not about a long and short size memory (Memoria de largo o corto plazo). Saludos

Answer (score 0):

I did not see a translation that I like. I would probable stick to something simple, such as `Memoria de largo y corto plazo`.

Comment: Bienvenido Juan Manuel. Ten en cuenta que se pregunta por el significado relacionado con **redes neuronales** en cuyo caso "long" no se refiere a memoria de largo plazo sino al tamaño de la memoria de corto plazo.

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't have an entry in Spanish for this term, but it does have one in Catalán -- maybe it would be helpful.  As far as I can tell the term describes a model used in Artificial Intelligence, not in describing organic cerebral functioning!